# Taking a screenshot of a particular window

Tags: c#, image, winapi

I've got a function which takes a screenshot of a particular window. It's important that the screenshot works whether the window is focused/covered by other windows or not, hence why I've used `PrintWindow`.

This function takes 45ms to complete, and I was hoping to decrease that. The end goal is to:

- Take a screenshot of a window based on a `handle`, which works even if the window is covered by a different window
- Finally return a `byte[]` to be exported as a PNG using NodeJS.

screenshot.cs

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class main
{
   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   private struct Rect
   {
      public int Left;
      public int Top;
      public int Right;
      public int Bottom;
   }

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern IntPtr GetClientRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

   [DllImport("user32.dll")]
   private static extern IntPtr ClientToScreen(IntPtr hWnd, ref Point point);

   [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hDC, uint nFlags);

   public static Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
   {
      var rect = new Rect();
      GetClientRect(handle, ref rect);

      var point = new Point(0,0);
      ClientToScreen(handle, ref point);

      var bounds = new Rectangle(point.X, point.Y, rect.Right, rect.Bottom);
      var result = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

      using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
      {
         IntPtr dc = graphics.GetHdc();
         bool success = PrintWindow(handle, dc, 0);
         graphics.ReleaseHdc(dc);
      }

      return result;
   }

   public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
   {
      ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
      return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
   }
}
```

NodeJS code

```
const {K, U} = require('win32-api');
const user32 = U.load();
const edge = require('edge-js');
const ss = edge.func(path.join(__dirname, 'screenshot.cs'));

var hWnd = user32.FindWindowExW(0, 0, null, Buffer.from('application\0', 'ucs2'))
ss(hWnd, function (err, r) { fs.writeFileSync("screenshot.png", r); });
```

Comment: What is `ImageToByte` for? It doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: What is the expected formatting for `byte[]`? The .NET docs are woefully inadequate in describing how it does that particular conversion. A simple `LockBits` and then a buffer copy takes a fraction of the time that `converter.ConvertTo` takes, but the resulting byte array is not formatted at all the same as what's there now.

Comment: `ImageToByte( CaptureWindow(hWnd) )` is returned to a `nodejs` application and exported as a `png` file using `fs.writeFileSync`

Comment: Obligatory "have you used a profiler?" comment.  This will give you various metrics so you can target optimizations..

Comment: Please include all relevant parts of the code. It looks like some of the core essentials are missing, which makes optimizing for performance unnecessarily hard on the reviewers.

Comment: The only other code is the nodejs code that simply calls the C# function and outputs to a png file, which is one line. The query on performance only relates to the function shown.

Comment: @Mast I've added the `nodejs` code that calls the C# function and creates the `PNG` and a missing struct declaration

Comment: This code looks familiar; I seem to recall having done something similar, and it was also slower than I'd initially expected.  I think I came to the conclusion that, if I wanted better performance, I'd need to use GPU primitives rather than hoisting the image into the .NET-VM for fully-CPU-bound processing.

Comment: You might want to see if this could be on-topic at [SE.ComputerGraphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/).  Folks there might be more familiar with the details of optimizing stuff like this.